# Bootstrap 3 Dropdown on Tablet - Double Tap Parent nav element with href?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

In Bootstrap 3, I want to have a navbar which is shown on hover or tap (depending if you're on desktop or tablet respectively).

I have accomplished this, but the issue is that on any navbar `<li>` elements that contain an `<a>` element with a `href`, I am not able to navigate to the `href`. The goal would be a click, or second tap on tablet.

Is there a way to do this? In my code, the `<li>` with the text "dropdown" should be able to navigate you to an external URL.

http://jsfiddle.net/2Smgv/3917/

Comment: Turned out I had another JS library conflicting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try following js code to your page

```
$(function(){
  $('.nav-pills .dropdown .dropdown-toggle').bind('mousedown', function(){
  var href = $(this).attr('href');
  location.href = href;
 });
});
```